# Finding the value 'n' in an array that has 'n' or more larger values

Tags: java, array, interview-questions

> Given an unsorted array of integers, you need to return maximum possible \$n\$ 
>   such that the array consists at least \$n\$ values greater than or equals
>   to \$n\$. Array can contain duplicate values.
>
> Sample 1
>
> ```
> input : [1, 2, 3, 4]
> output: 2
> ```
>
> Sample 2
>
> ```
> input : [900, 2, 901, 3, 1000]
> output: 3
> ```

What do you folks think of my code to this problem?

```
      public static Integer findN(Integer[] values) {
        Comparator comparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {
          @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
              return o2.compareTo(o1);
            }
        };
        Arrays.sort(values, comparator);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (i >= values[i]) {
                return values[i];
            }
        }
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right now, after you sort the array, you're doing a linear search for the correct value. I believe you should be able to write that part of the task using a binary search instead of a linear search.

The sorting has a minimum complexity of \$O(N log N)\$, so reducing the search from \$O(N)\$ to \$O(log N)\$ won't affect the overall computational complexity, but for any more than a small number of items, it should still reduce the overall time.

Comment: Binary search is the better strategy! +1

Comment: How does binary search help?

Comment: @bazang: With a binary search, you can expect to look at  approximately log N items to find your target. With a linear search, you can expect to look at approximately N/2 items instead.

Answer (score 8):

You haven't **declared** the `Comparator` with generics, only instantiated it with Generics. In fact, you get a compiler warning on the `Arrays.sort` line saying

> Type safety: Unchecked invocation sort(Integer[], Comparator) of the generic method sort(T[], Comparator) of type Arrays

Better would be

```
Comparator<Integer> comparator = new Comparator<Integer>() {
```

---

There is nothing in the description saying that you should return `Integer.MIN_VALUE` for an empty array. I think it would be better to throw an exception.

There's no need to return an `Integer` when you can return `int`.

You're using generics so that you can use your own comparator. An alternative (not saying it's better or worse) would be to use pure `int[]`, sort the array as usual, and then loop through the array backwards:

```
public static int findN(int[] values) {
    Arrays.sort(values);
    for (int i = values.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int indexFromEnd = values.length - 1 - i;
        if (indexFromEnd >= values[i]) {
            return values[i];
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array cannot be empty");
}
```

You might want to "fail-fast" instead and throwing the exception at the top, but then you'd have to throw an `AssertionError` or similar at the bottom.

Comment: I will say that using `int[]` is better.